# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' problem while using AdamAccumulate

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

When I use this AdamAccumulate code from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3556#issuecomment-440638517) for Image Classification with TensorFlow and Keras but it shows this error.

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

I use TensorFlow 2.2.0' and Keras 2.3.0-tf in Google Colab.

I try to downgrade to TensorFlow but it doesn't help. But when I use in Kaggle, it's fine, so I don't know how to fix it. I want to run this code in Google Colab.

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras.optimizers import Optimizer

class AdamAccumulate(Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                 epsilon=None, decay=0., amsgrad=False, accum_iters=1, **kwargs):
        if accum_iters < 1:
            raise ValueError('accum_iters must be >= 1')
        super(AdamAccumulate, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
            self.lr = K.variable(lr, name='lr')
            self.beta_1 = K.variable(beta_1, name='beta_1')
            self.beta_2 = K.variable(beta_2, name='beta_2')
            self.decay = K.variable(decay, name='decay')
        if epsilon is None:
            epsilon = K.epsilon()
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.initial_decay = decay
        self.amsgrad = amsgrad
        self.accum_iters = K.variable(accum_iters, K.dtype(self.iterations))
        self.accum_iters_float = K.cast(self.accum_iters, K.floatx())

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr

        completed_updates = K.cast(K.tf.floordiv(self.iterations, self.accum_iters), K.floatx())

        if self.initial_decay > 0:
            lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * completed_updates))

        t = completed_updates + 1

        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(self.beta_2, t)) / (1. - K.pow(self.beta_1, t)))

        # self.iterations incremented after processing a batch
        # batch:              1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        # self.iterations:    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
        # update_switch = 1:        x       x    (if accum_iters=4)  
        update_switch = K.equal((self.iterations + 1) % self.accum_iters, 0)
        update_switch = K.cast(update_switch, K.floatx())

        ms = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        vs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        gs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]

        if self.amsgrad:
            vhats = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        else:
            vhats = [K.zeros(1) for _ in params]

        self.weights = [self.iterations] + ms + vs + vhats

        for p, g, m, v, vhat, tg in zip(params, grads, ms, vs, vhats, gs):

            sum_grad = tg + g
            avg_grad = sum_grad / self.accum_iters_float

            m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * avg_grad
            v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(avg_grad)

            if self.amsgrad:
                vhat_t = K.maximum(vhat, v_t)
                p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(vhat_t) + self.epsilon)
                self.updates.append(K.update(vhat, (1 - update_switch) * vhat + update_switch * vhat_t))
            else:
                p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)

            self.updates.append(K.update(m, (1 - update_switch) * m + update_switch * m_t))
            self.updates.append(K.update(v, (1 - update_switch) * v + update_switch * v_t))
            self.updates.append(K.update(tg, (1 - update_switch) * sum_grad))
            new_p = p_t

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, (1 - update_switch) * p + update_switch * new_p))
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'lr': float(K.get_value(self.lr)),
                  'beta_1': float(K.get_value(self.beta_1)),
                  'beta_2': float(K.get_value(self.beta_2)),
                  'decay': float(K.get_value(self.decay)),
                  'epsilon': self.epsilon,
                  'amsgrad': self.amsgrad}
        base_config = super(AdamAccumulate, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Comment: Wait a second. Didn't python give you an entire traceback including the failing line?

Comment: Could you add some more of the of the error message?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm sure there are no lines missing. I tried almost all of the code from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3556) but still stuck with this problem.

Comment: Its unfortunate that the traceback was supressed, then. I see nearly a hundred lines of code and no indication of which line failed. Are you running this in an IDE? Maybe try the command line to see if you get decent error messages. Python tries to make this easy by including a trace when an exception is raised. Tools that supress that information can be infuriating.

Comment: @tdelaney When I use this code I run in Google Colab, when I try this code on my JupyterLab it still stuck with this problem. But when I use in Kaggle it fine.

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen It shows an error just like that but you can check my notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eVkHSF_AtjUJDH2YBkVMYDTnyVyhJNL6?usp=sharing)

Comment: First rule of stackoverflow club: Include full debug traces. Your notebook showed you exactly which line in your program failed: `super(AdamAccumulate, self).__init__(**kwargs)`. You inherit from `Optimizer` and it expects a "name" parameter. You really need to post that stuff.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm sorry for not following the rules but how to fix this bug?. I really want a solution to solve this problem, so help me, please.

Comment: This link talks about subclassing `Optimizer`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#write_a_customized_optimizer_2. I don't know what restrictions `name` has, but my guess is that `super(AdamAccumulate, self).__init__("AdamAccumulate", **kwargs)` will do. Assuming this is python 3, the defaults for `super` would also work: ``super().__init__("AdamAccumulate", **kwargs)`